# Force PHP to skip "exit"

Tags: php

Is there a short solution to avoid the execution of the "exit" language construct? Otherwise I'll have to execute my function with another PHP-request.

Sample: main.php

```
echo 'hello world';
doSomething();
updateSomething();
```

Sample: doSomething.php

```
function doSomething()
{
$a = 1+1;
exit;
}
```

Sample: updateSomething.php

```
function updateSomething()
{
$b = 3+5;
exit;
}
```

But the second function will never be executed ...is there a simple solution? I've found two existing topics, without a real solution. But maybe there is smart trick for my example?

It's not a real example, in my case the functions represents some complex methods, which are called with ajax reqests without a return statement. Because the method are from a external library, I can't modify the code. And I want to call two methods of this library in one single script, if it's possible :)

And ... I know what `return` is doing, but in my case I can't modify the code, because it's not my code - it's code from an existing software and I just want to call these existing methods in a custom script. But I can just call one of the methods because of the exit-function in every method and it would be great to call them multiple times.

Comment: Just use return; https://eval.in/56196

Comment: Yes. Remove the `exit;` from the function...

Comment: Why using `exit();` in your code if you don't need it? Your first function can return a boolean value indicating its success or failure, this will allow you to test the returned value to decide if you want to execute the second function.

Comment: It's not a real example, in my case the functions represents some complex methods, which are called with ajax reqests without a `return` statement. Because the method are from a external library, I can't modify the code. And I want to call two methods of this library in one single script, if it's possible :)

Comment: I would also say that the most natural way to make script to *skip* `exit()` is to remove it.

Comment: WHY? What is the purpose? call PHP Team.

Comment: @StefanBrendle toss the library. It's broken.

Comment: @BartFriedrichs: It's not a real library, it's a part of a existing software. And just want to use this methods as well for a custom script.

Comment: Well you can't use it 'as is', you need to either modify it or ditch it, there are no other alternatives.

Comment: @vascowhite: No problem, I just wanted to know, if there is a trick or another pissiblity. If it's not possible, I'll have to take another solution. Didn't expect that much downvotes ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to skip or disable an "exit" command.

If you want to do something before the script stops, you can use shutdown-functions or object-destructors ... but I don't think that's something you're up to, is it?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php

Comment: why not? I think he can use `variable functions` and `eval` to achieve his goal =)

Comment: @EL, Because that would prequire the user to change his code :p

Answer (score 2):

Simple. Remove `exit;` from the functions.

[`exit()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php) will terminate execution from the script. You probably want to use [`return`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php) which returns back to the calling code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I don't want to use `return`, because it's not my code - it's code from an existing software and I just want to call these existing methods in a custom script. But I can just call one of the methods because of the `exit`-function in every method and it would be great to call them multiple times.

Comment: @Stefan Brendle that depends how you call these scripts. I think you can possibly achieve this with `eval`

Answer (score 2):

The year is 2020 and a way to do what question author wanted to now exists - you can install [uopz extension](https://pecl.php.net/package/uopz) from PECL (version 5.0.2 or above), and use [uopz_allow_exit()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uopz-allow-exit.php) function to disable exit()'s, like this:

```php
echo 'hello world';

uopz_allow_exit( false );
doSomething();
updateSomething();
uopz_allow_exit( true );
```

Note, however, that you will need to add this config option into your php.ini file:

```
uopz.exit = 1
```

If you dont, then ***all exit() calls will be disabled by default everywhere***  unless explicitly enabled by uopz_allow_exit().

It is also worth noting that this config option appeared only in version 6.0.1, which, for me at least, failed to install on PHP 7.0, and worked only on 7.2

Oh, and according to the documentation this extension is supposed to be used for unit testing, not production. Then again, nothing in it says that using this extension in production is discouraged, so it's your call.

Answer (score 0):

From the manual:

> Terminates execution of the script.

`exit` (alias of `die`) is the final thing the script does. Switch to an alternative use

```
function doSomething()
{
   $a = 1+1;
   return true;
}
```